# Data from such a repository can't be authenticated

Tags: repository

I am getting a below error when I do

```
sudo apt-get update


Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:    /Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Can anyone tell what might be the issue

EDIT:
Output of 
    cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main
```

Comment: Please can you post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I was installing arc-theme recently, it worked fine though. Can that be a reason ?

Comment: You have invalid `sources.list` and this is the case. You might have added some invalid PPAs to your list.

Comment: cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main

Comment: Please, post the output of the command as an edit, as you see comments cannot contain more than one line...

Comment: Just updated the output as an edit

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all make sure that, this works:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt-get update
```

If it did not work, count that, I did not found any other choice for you besides running

```
sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated
```

This is a security risk, but if you are ready for this you can use `--allow-unauthenticated` flag for some other apt commands.

Comment: Deleting the two files before calling *update* works.

Comment: worked like charm, will you explain what is happening :D

Comment: @Vinujan.S, it just deletes other ppa entries from computer.