# Installing GParted Live using Tuxboot

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, gparted

I am trying to install GParted Live using Tuxboot as suggested [here](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php#linux-method-a) (Method A). When I go to install Tuxboot by following either of the 3 options suggested [here](https://tuxboot.org/download/), I encounter either of the following problems:

1- When I install the binary executable files from SourceForge or OSDN, and go on to do the second step suggested [here](https://tuxboot.org/installation/) under "USB setup with GNU/Linux" I don't find the `./tuxboot-linux*` file. Only the windows version.

2-
If I do `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot` then I get:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                          
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                        
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                             
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot/ubuntu focal InRelease                           
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                         
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                   
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot/ubuntu focal Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So then I searched for this error I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995484/data-from-such-a-repository-cant-be-authenticated). I followed the instructions given by the accepted answer, and that didn't change anything.

So I then found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244349/getting-following-error-after-the-command-sudo-apt-get-update-on-ubuntu-16-04). I tried following the instructions of the answer with the highest number of votes, and when I open the Software Updater, I get `Failed to download repository information`.

Not sure what to do now?

PS: deleting the file `thomas_tsai-ubuntu-ubuntu-tuxboot-focal.list` from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` solved the Software Updater issue, but I'm still at a loss as to how to go about the other points I brought up

Comment: @KK Patel no it doesn't

Comment: If you're trying to use a software [that's not been developed for ages](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxboot/files/), I don't see what you can do except use [a release that it did have builds for](https://launchpad.net/~thomas.tsai/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-tuxboot).